# Kotlin, quero saber como faço para através do clique no botão passar de um fragmento para outro

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin

Tenho dois fragmentos, e quero navegar do primeiro para o segundo através do clique no botão.

Meu código do fragmento está assim e o id do botão é "questaoUmBotao".

```
class QuestaoUm : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questao_um, container, false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a mudança de fragment ao clicar em um botão, você somente precisa fazer a mudança de fragment usando o código abaixo ao clicar no botão.

```
val fragmentDestino = FragmentDestino()
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.rootView, fragmentDestino)
transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma API que pode nos ajudar com isso, é a FragmentTransaction.
Para pegarmos uma instância dessa API, podemos fazer assim.

```
val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
```

Agora, para podermos realizar a transação de uma fragment  para a outra quando tu clicar no botão, temos que fazer algo assim.

```
questaoUmBotao.setOnClickListener {
  val fragmentDois: Fragment = QuestaoDois()
  val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentDois)
  transaction.commit()
}
```